# Issue with recording from the Open ONVIF (Network Video Interface Forum ) device

Tags: java, networking, recording, ip-camera, onvif

I'm working on Open Network Video Interface Forum-Java project and following the steps described in the [ONVIF Application Programmer's Guide](http://www.openipcam.com/files/ONVIF/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmer%27s_Guide.pdf).

I have generated sources from the `wsdls` provided in ONVIF site. I'm able to retrieve the live stream URI using the `media.wsdl`. Now I have an issue with recording. The codes that I have tried is given below:

```
RecordingService recording_ervice = new RecordingService();
RecordingPort record_port = recording_ervice.getRecordingPort();


BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) record_port;

// Add a security handler for the credentials
final Binding binding = bindingProvider.getBinding();
List<Handler> handlerList = binding.getHandlerChain();
if (handlerList == null) {
    handlerList = new ArrayList<Handler>();
}

handlerList.add(new RecordStream.SecurityHandler());
// binding.setHandlerChain(handlerList);

// Set the actual web services address instead of the mock service
Map<String, Object> requestContext = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();

requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://" + deviceip + "/onvif/media_service");
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, user);
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, pass);

Recordings recordings = record_port.getRecordings();
```

The above code on run gives an error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Method 'ns11:GetServiceCapabilities' not implemented: method name or namespace not recognized
```

I also tried with media service, then the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 405: Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: note that "recording" is the service used by ONVIF recorders: most ip cameras don't support it. I think you should check it in the device capabilities, since it is an optional service (depends on the supported profile): http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/GetCapabilities. One more note: in the last line you are assigning getRecordings() to "capabilities"... looking at http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/recording.wsdl - I would say that this is the output type for GetServiceCapabilities(). Just double check it too.

Comment: security policies of web server should be examined, as method seems to be exist in code but not allowed or reachable by client.

Comment: Agree with Ved... Whoever is implementing this WSDL has either not implemented certain features or the namespace is pointing to a WSDL declaration which does not include the function.  Personally, I'm a bit taken aback by this ONVIF choice of WSDL.

Answer (score 2):

When you tried with the media source, you requested an unauthorized action apparently since the server returned Error code 405. Either the method is prohibited from use, or you need a credential to use the method.

As for `Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Method 'ns11:GetServiceCapabilities' not implemented: method name or namespace not recognized`, @Sigismondo is right about the fact that most ip cameras don't support it. You will need an alternative recording method(literal and pun) to record from an ip camera.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `http://" + deviceip + "/onvif/media_service` to reach the Recording service, but this is a [media.wsdl](http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl) service. So when you try to call getRecordings on the media service it seems normal you receive an error.

The url for [recording.wsdl](http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/recording.wsdl) service should be `http://" + deviceip + "/onvif/recording_service`.

In order to get the corect URL to reach the recording service you should request it from the GetCapabilities method of the [devicemgmt.wsdl](http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl) service.

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP 405 - Resource not allowed** usually occurs in IIS.
This problem occurs if the following conditions are true:

- You do not specify the file name. For example, you do not specify
  http ://Server/Web/...
- The Scripting Object Model (SOM) is enabled.
- A DTC event is called.

So, when the SOM is enabled a **< form >** tag is inserted in the page the tag is invalid means it does not contain any action.